# full screen soft keyboard for portrait view

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

In android there is an option to set full screen soft keyboard for portrait view.  I have seen the full screen keyboard in only landscape view, when we click `EditText`.

I have learned we can disable it to. But can we enable it for portrait view?

Comment: I didn't get your question. Do you want to enable full screen soft keyboard for portrait view?